# How to calculate the number of nodes in a JSON string

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to calculate the number of nodes in a `JSON` in SQL.

```
{   
 "File":[  
  {  
     "ID":1,
     "Fragment":"Frag1"
  },
  {  
     "ID":2,
     "Fragment":"Frag2"
  },
  {  
     "ID":3,
     "Fragment":"Frag3"
  }]
}
```

Is there a way to count the number of child elements under `File` node?

Answer should be 3 according to the above example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server version 2016 or higher,
You can use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and `select count(*)`:

```
DECLARE @Content varchar(500) = '{   
 "File":[  
  {  
     "ID":1,
     "Fragment":"Frag1"
  },
  {  
     "ID":2,
     "Fragment":"Frag2"
  },
  {  
     "ID":3,
     "Fragment":"Frag3"
  }]
}';

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM OPENJSON(@Content, N'$.File')
```

Result: `3`

See a live demo on [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ea30eda47c395394e4f1d3b457bc0e2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(MyObjectList.ID)
    FROM Mytable
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (JsonDataCol, N'$.File')
      WITH (
        ID int)
          AS MyObjectList
```

Comment: While this answer might resolve the OP's question, it is suggested that you explain how it works and why it resolves the issue. This helps new developers understand what is going on and how to fix this and similar issues themselves. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach where Json string is inserted into the table. You can run this in lower Sql Server versions like SQL Server 2008 also where OPENJSON function is not available.

```
create table #temp (JsonDataCol varchar(max))
insert into #temp values (

'{   
 "File":[  
  {  
     "ID":1,
     "Fragment":"Frag1"
  },
  {  
     "ID":2,
     "Fragment":"Frag2"
  },
  {  
     "ID":3,
     "Fragment":"Frag3"
  }
}'

)

DECLARE @string Varchar(20) = '"ID"'
DECLARE @tosearch Varchar(Max)

set @tosearch = (SELECT JsonDataCol FROM #temp)

SELECT (LEN(@tosearch) - LEN(REPLACE(@tosearch, 'ID', '')))/2 as JsonLength

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Here divided by 2 because length of ID is 2 and it's one occurrence is 1 node.
You can also run this query without table if you will assign @tosearch variable as shown below

```
DECLARE @tosearch Varchar(Max) = '{   
 "File":[  
  {  
     "ID":1,
     "Fragment":"Frag1"
  },
  {  
     "ID":2,
     "Fragment":"Frag2"
  },
  {  
     "ID":3,
     "Fragment":"Frag3"
  }
}'
```

The output is as shown below

```
JsonLength
3
```

You can find live demo on link  [**SQL Demo - Json Length**](https://rextester.com/XHGO44092)